# Gradle build: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL https using artifactory

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

In the build.gradle of a module, I'm trying to execute the following line

```
if (!jsonFile.exists()) {
    new URL(mapUrl).withInputStream{ i -> jsonFile.withOutputStream{ it << i }}
}
```

The build fails with the error:

```
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://artifactory.myurl.com/artifactory/myfile.json
```

I pass the credentials to my gradle script as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url 'https://artifactory.myurl.com/artifactory/'
            credentials {
                username = "myuser"
                password = "mypwd"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are several problems in your code:

First, `withInputStream` and `withOutputStream` are Groovy JDK enhancements on the Java classes `URL` and `File`. This is not related to any Gradle functionality and only works, because Gradle is built on top of Groovy. As far as I know, it is not possible to pass credentials to `withInputStream`, so it only works for resources that are publicly available.

Regarding the second part of your code snippet, lets first take a look at the `buildscript` block. It is a special Gradle block that always will be evaluated first (and must be at the top of a `build.gradle` file). The reason for this is that this block basically provides as a setup for your build script (aka the `build.gradle` file). Usually this block defines the `repositories` and the `dependencies` that need to be resolved for the build script to work (e.g. plugins). Regular project `dependencies` and their `repositories` may be defined outside of the `buildscript` block. They are resolved when other task (e.g. compilation tasks) need them.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'example-plugins:my-fancy-plugin:0.0.1'
    }
}
// the build script stops here to resolve my-fancy-plugin from jcenter

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'example-libraries:my-cool-library:0.0.1'
}
// this won't be resolved directly, only if a task that needs *implementation* dependencies is run
```

The `repositories`/`dependencies` mechanism is mainly used to resolve `*.jar` files that serve as dependencies of JVM-based projects. The repositories are usually Maven repositories. Maven repositories follow a specific layout, so the dependency descriptors (e.g. `example-libraries:my-cool-library:0.0.1`) will be mapped to URLs (e.g. `example/libraries/my-cool-library/0.0.1/my-cool-library-0.0.1.jar`). Gradle then tries to download the dependencies from this URL. Since your path does not follow the Maven repository layout, you can't download your file from a Maven repository.

For your use case you probably should not use the Gradle dependency resolution at all. There is a [plugin](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task) that allows downloading files using a Gradle task (with support for authentication):

```
task downloadFile(type: Download) {
    src 'https://artifactory.myurl.com/artifactory/myfile.json'
    username = "myuser"
    password = "mypwd"
    dest buildDir
}
```

Alternatively you may define an Ivy repository with a [custom repository layout](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html#sub:defining_custom_pattern_layout_for_an_ivy_repository).

Comment: That make sense. I'll try the gradle download plugin to pass credentials. Thanks !